# <a href> inside mobile:SelectionList

Tags: .net, asp.net, mobile, mobile-website

I am trying to place `<a href='somepage'>` inside the selection list like below but somehow its not rendering...

```
<Mobile:SelectionList runat="server" id="cars" SelectType="CheckBox" > 
   <Item Text="I agree to <a href='test'>test terms &amp; condition</a>" value="Value" Selected="False" />
 </Mobile:SelectionList>
```

here is the out i get:

```
[CHECKBOX] I agree to <a href='test'>test terms & condition</a>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WOW mobile controls!! You should know it is a deprecated technology. I think [you can not use](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6xzzk69d%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) controls inside of selectionlist. But you can use better a repeater control.

Comment: what? i am not sure i understand what you trying to say but what do you mean by deprecated tech? why would i use repeater control for checkbox?

Comment: This api is obsolete. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.mobilecontrols.mobilepage.aspx

Answer (score 1):

```
<Mobile:SelectionList runat="server" id="cars" SelectType="CheckBox" > 
   <Item Text="I agree to &lt;a href='test'&gt; test terms &amp; condition&lt;/a&gt;" value="Value" Selected="False" />
 </Mobile:SelectionList>
```